# Running transition a few times using a function call

Tags: javafx, transition

I'm trying to use javaFX transition classes. I wrote this function, which animates a `Labal` into a specific location in my `Scene`.

The problem is, the animation that is shown is only for the last call of the function. 
Here is the call loop:

```
List<Player> tempList = myTable.getPlayersOnTable();
for (int i = 0 ; i < myTable.getNumberOfPlayers() ; ++i) {
    dealCardsAnimation(tempList.get(i).getHand().get(0).getHandCards().getCard(0), i);
    dealCardsAnimation(tempList.get(i).getHand().get(0).getHandCards().getCard(1), i);
}

private void dealCardsAnimation(Card card, int playerIndex) {
    ImageView cardImage = new ImageView("resources/cards/" 
                                         + card.getSuit().toString() + "/" 
                                         + card.getRank().toString() + ".png");
    cardImage.setFitWidth(72);
    cardImage.setFitHeight(113);    
    deckLabel.setGraphic(cardImage);
    playersCardsLocation.get(playerIndex).insertCardToGrid(deckLabel);

}
```

and the function itself:

> `private AnchorPane cardsGridPane; private int index;`
>
> ```
> public void insertCardToGrid(Label card) {
>     double x = card.getLayoutX();
>     double y = card.getLayoutY();
>     FlowPane temp = (FlowPane) (cardsGridPane.getChildren().get(index));
>
>     TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), card);
>     translate.setToX(cardsGridPane.getLayoutX() + temp.getLayoutX() - x);
>     translate.setToY(cardsGridPane.getLayoutY() + temp.getLayoutY() - y);
>
>     RotateTransition rotate = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), card);
>     rotate.setToAngle(temp.getRotate());
>
>     ParallelTransition transition = new ParallelTransition(translate, rotate);
>     transition.play();
>
>     card.setLayoutX(x);
>     card.setLayoutY(y);
>     index++;
> }
> ```

One last thing - when I add this line:

> ```
>     temp.getChildren().add(card.getGraphic());
> ```

at the end of `insertCardToGrid` I don't see any animation, just the final state of the grid after inserting the graphics.
Any help?

Comment: May your cards be overlapping each other while animating? Try to post a SSCCE.